# Advanced build and Link errors in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++

This post presents two errors on two different solution files in visual studio 2019

After cloning some code from GitHub, I tried building it on Visual Studio 2019 and I am told "Severity  Code    Description
Project File    Line    Suppression State
**Error MSB8020 The build tools for v143 (Platform Toolset = 'v143') cannot be found.**
To build using the v143 build tools, p**lease install v143 build tools**.
Alternatively, you may upgrade to the current Visual Studio tools by selecting
**the Project menu or right-click the solution, and then selecting "Retarget solution"**.
RPGSystemsUnitTest  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets  439 "

But I tried everything suggested and nothing worked.  Please advise.

=======================

In order to get this build and link completed regardless of this error, I decided to create a new solution and I added .cpp and .h empty files and copied the contents of the previous solution one file at a time.  While doing this I would build the code peridoically to make sure I was not haing any problems.

Eventually I reached a point where I was getting tons of LNK2019 error.  I am a bit rusty and I do not know how to solve. LNK2019 errors such as:

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "protected: void __thiscall **StatBlock::increase_stats**(unsigned int,unsigned int,unsigned int,unsigned int,unsigned int)" (?increase_stats@StatBlock@@IAEXIIIII@Z) **referenced in function** "public: __thiscall **Cleric::Cleric(void)**" (??0Cleric@@QAE@XZ)   demo_rpg    g:\Users\William Thompson\source\repos\demo_rpg\demo_rpg**cleric**.obj 1
Here is a clue.  demo_rpg is a library. After changing this, how do I link the RPGPrototype to it?

[image]

Comment: The linker errors mean that the code you are compiling and linking is looking for functions and such from the code you aren't compiling and linking. If you're adding files one at a time this is inevitable and you just need to add the files that the current code depends on too. Why are you using 2019 and not 2022? I don't have 2019 handy to know if you can install the v143 toolchain in it or not but it is the default in 2022.